# Convert datatype Clob to Varchar2 Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, clob, varchar2

I have an Oracle table with a column of type clob. I want to preserve the column order and change the datatype to a varchar2. The column just contains text.

```
update IN_MSG_BOARD set MSG_TEXT = null;
alter table IN_MSG_BOARD modify MSG_TEXT long;
alter table IN_MSG_BOARD modify MSG_TEXT varchar2(4000);
```

I'm getting the standard message:

> ORA-22859: invalid modification of columns

I have tried making the column null and then converting to char or long, then to varchar2. But nothing seems to be working. I would prefer to not have to copy the table to change the one column.

I don't just want to read the contents. I want to change the datatype of the column from clob to varchar2.

Help would be greatly appreciated. I have been working on this for a while. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You are taking a risk that by converting the data you will truncate any strings that are longer than 4000 characters.  Are you sure all your data is less than 4000 characters?

Comment: The column order shouldn't really matter. Is there a reason you need to preserve it?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731301/clob-vs-varchar2-and-are-there-other-alternatives)

Comment: @kevinsky - I'm sure the strings are less than 4000 characters. Made sure to check that.

Comment: And, @alex poole, unfortunately the way this project was setup the original dev made the column order matter and hardcoded it into the background. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop CLOB column, add the varchar2 column, and then 'fix' the column order using [online table redefinition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN01514); assuming you're on a version that supports that and you have permission to use the `DBMS_REDEFINITION` package. Very simple demo for a table with a primary key:

```
create table in_msg_board(col1 number primary key, msg_text clob, col3 date);
```

If you don't want to keep the data in your original column:

```
alter table IN_MSG_BOARD drop column msg_text;
alter table IN_MSG_BOARD add msg_text varchar2(4000);
```

If you do want to keep the data it's only two extra steps, shown in the rowid version below.

Create a redefinition table, with the columns in the order you want:

```
create table in_msg_board_redef(col1 number, msg_text varchar2(4000), col3 date);
```

And call the package:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(
    uname => user,
    orig_table => 'IN_MSG_BOARD',
    int_table => 'IN_MSG_BOARD_REDEF',
    col_mapping => 'col1 col1, msg_text msg_text, col3 col3');
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(uname => user,
    orig_table => 'IN_MSG_BOARD',
    int_table => 'IN_MSG_BOARD_REDEF');
END;
/

desc in_msg_board;

Name     Null Type           
-------- ---- -------------- 
COL1          NUMBER         
MSG_TEXT      VARCHAR2(4000) 
COL3          DATE
```

There is more in the documentation about checking the table is valid for redefinition, handling dependent tables (foreign keys) etc.

---

If your table doesn't have a primary key then [you can use rowids](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11668) by passing an additional option flag. For this demo I'll preserve the data too.

```
create table in_msg_board(col1 number, msg_text clob, col3 date);
insert into in_msg_board values (1, 'This is a test', sysdate);
alter table IN_MSG_BOARD add msg_text_new varchar2(4000);
update IN_MSG_BOARD set msg_text_new = dbms_lob.substr(msg_text, 4000, 1);
alter table IN_MSG_BOARD drop column msg_text;
alter table IN_MSG_BOARD rename column msg_text_new to msg_text;

desc in_msg_board

Name     Null Type           
-------- ---- -------------- 
COL1          NUMBER         
COL3          DATE           
MSG_TEXT      VARCHAR2(4000)
```

So as before, at this point the new column (containing data this time) is there but in the wrong position. So redefine as before, but with the `DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID` flag:

```
create table in_msg_board_redef(col1 number, msg_text varchar2(4000), col3 date);

BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(
    uname => user,
    orig_table => 'IN_MSG_BOARD',
    int_table => 'IN_MSG_BOARD_REDEF',
    col_mapping => 'col1 col1, msg_text msg_text, col3 col3',
    options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(uname => user,
    orig_table => 'IN_MSG_BOARD',
    int_table => 'IN_MSG_BOARD_REDEF');
END;
/

desc in_msg_board;

Name     Null Type           
-------- ---- -------------- 
COL1          NUMBER         
MSG_TEXT      VARCHAR2(4000) 
COL3          DATE
```

And the data is there too:

```
select * from in_msg_board;

      COL1 MSG_TEXT             COL3    
---------- -------------------- ---------
         1 This is a test       27-MAY-15
```

And as mentioned in the linked documentation, you can then drop the hidden column used to manage the rowids:

```
alter table in_msg_board drop unused columns;
```

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I'm reading through the documentation now.

Comment: So my table doesn't have a primary key. You said that is a requirement to use online table redefinition?

Comment: @bbanks - well, it's easier; [there is a rowid method too](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11668) but I haven't used that. The demo was for the PK version.

Comment: @bbanks - added an example using rowids.

Comment: Of course, with no dependencies, it might be simpler to just CTAS a new table, drop (or rename) the original, and rename the new one back to `in_msg_board`. Unless you have to make this change online, with no or limited downtime, and the alter/update might take a while anyway. You didn't say why you didn't want to create a new table.

Comment: I got it figured out. Thanks so much for the help. I did end up recreating the table and just changing that column on creation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do next steps :

```
1. alter table my_table add (new_column varchar2(4000));

2. update my_table set new_column = dbms_lob.substr(old_column,4000,1);

3. alter table my_table drop column old_column
```

Comment: You'd also need to rename the new column; I showed that in my answer too *8-) But this doesn't address the requirement to preserve the column order.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ibrahim. But like Alex said, this doesn't keep the column order.